# Multiple Attachment problems in PL/SQL using utl_smtp package

Tags: plsql, mime, attachment, email

I'm using the code from this link to send attachments in the email notifications of our system;

http://www.builderau.com.au/program/oracle/soa/Sending-blob-attachments-in-e-mail-with-utl-smtp/0,339028441,339284536,00.htm

The problem is that the second attachment has encoding issue. So if i send in a text file, the text in the txt file will be all mashed up.. Like the first 23 characters are printed correctly then there is a mash of text like 'B•Ú]\ÈØ]\‹[ÝH' then it continues with the text and same thing happens after 23 characters again...

For the first attachment, I print the MIME boundary;

```
    utl_smtp.write_data(g_mail_conn, chr(13)||chr(10)||chr(13)||chr(10)||'--' || l_boundary ||
                chr(13) || chr(10));

utl_smtp.write_data( g_mail_conn, 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test2.txt"' || chr(13) || chr(10));
utl_smtp.write_data( g_mail_conn, 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64' || chr(13) || chr(10) );
```

Then I run the while loop that i took from the link (copied below as well) and then after the loop, I reset the v_offset variable, then i put the same code above for the second boundary for the attachment.. Then i close the MIME boundaries at the end with

```
utl_smtp.write_data(g_mail_conn,chr(13) || chr(10) || '--' ||  l_boundary || '--' || chr(13));
```

Any ideas why this problem is happening?

The While loop;

```
<<while_loop>>
while v_offset < v_length loop
  dbms_lob.read( p_blob, v_buffer_size, v_offset, v_raw );
  utl_smtp.write_raw_data( c, utl_encode.base64_encode(v_raw) );
  utl_smtp.write_data( c, utl_tcp.crlf );
  v_offset := v_offset + v_buffer_size;
end loop while_loop;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just found the solution...

The v_buffer_size variable was getting modified in the dbms_lob.read() procedure, so before attaching the new file, I just had to reset it back to 57 along with setting v_offset to 1..

Comment: hmm... it also looks like if you make v_buffer_size := 57 and v_offset := 1 then every file with size (x*58)+1 will be truncated by last character